# TIFF Landsat file not displaying in ArcGIS Pro despite being uploaded

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff

I downloaded a Landsat image of Jamaica from the USGS Earth Explorer. I successfully uploaded the files with the metadata and bands that I wanted into one composite file using the composite bands tool. However, the raster layer will not display on the map. I tried getting rid of the pyramids with the build pyramid tool, and that didn't work.

Any ideas how I can get the image to display?

[image]

Comment: Check your projection and coordinates - is it possible that your image has loaded but is in the wrong location? Zoom to Layer can usually help you find a misplaced layer.